# Screenshot of element after scrolling to the element with Selenium + Python?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, python-imaging-library

I want to take a screenshot of an element from a website at Chrome. Before i take the screenshot, i scroll down to the element with following code:

```
element = self.browser.find_element_by_class_name("class_name")
print(game_table.location)
self.browser.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", element)
```

After this I wan't to take a screenshot of this element with help of PIL:

```
location = element.location
size = element.size
img = browser.get_screenshot_as_png()
img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(img))

left = location['x']
top = location['y']
right = left + size['width']
bottom = top + size['height']

cropBox = (left, top, right, bottom)

img = img.crop(cropBox)
img.save('screenshot.png')
```

`element.location` gives me the coordinates of the element. But a screenshot will be taken from the view only, so I need to subtract from y-location the height I scrolled down to get the position of the element in the view.

How I get the height I scrolled down? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: use `element.location_once_scrolled_into_view` to get the location in the viewport. `element.location` is the location relative to the document.

Comment: @FlorentB. Thanks! It works now. Please write an answer to mark the questeion as solved!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [Florent B.'s comment!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49907654/screenshot-of-element-after-scrolling-to-the-element-with-selenium-python#comment86834202_49907654)

I changed the line `location = element.location` to

```
location = element.location_once_scrolled_into_view
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use the `getBoundingClientRect` javascript function for this, not sure though. 
you can find the details documentation here.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect